# global ... is not defined python

Tags: python, global

I need to read some words text by text in python, and I am getting this error.
"NameError: global name 'wordList' is not defined.

```
i=0
with fitxer as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
              wordList[i]=word
              i+1
return wordList
```

Comment: Did you define `wordList` anywhere before `wordList[i]=word`…?

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. There is no variable named wordList, so you cannot do `wordList[i]=word`

Comment: And if you wish to add elements to your list, you should use the `append` method.

Comment: Your inner `for` loop is not necessary, `wordlist = line.split()`.  That is, `str.split()` returns a list anyway.

Comment: @cdarke That's not quite equivalent in this case.

Comment: @deceze: yup, you are right, I missed that.

Comment: By the way, do you realise that `i+1` does nothing?  Did you mean `i += 1`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define wordList to begin with. And you cannot randomly assign indexes in an empty list. You can easily 'extend' the list with new values.

```
worldList = []
with fitxer as f:
    for line in f:
        wordList.extend(line.split())
return wordList
```

Answer (score 0):

`wordList` is not instantiated as a list or not in scope.

<s>If `wordList` is a global variable, the beginning of your function will need `global wordList`</s> *Not needed because the object is mutated*

If the list should only be in scope of the function you will need to instantiate it as a list.

```
wordList = []
```

Edit: as [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) pointed out

Within the function itself you should be appending to the list since the index does not exists.

```
wordList.append(word)
```

Comment: Note that this will lead to an `IndexError`, the way the list is used here…

Comment: The function wouldn't require a `global` statement if `wordList` were indeed defined globally. Indeed, the fact that this error is showing means that `global` isn't necessary

Comment: You should specify that when defining a `global`, you should prefixe it with an underscore (`_`) (not talking about `__all__` here that is a whole another subject, but conventions should be respected, so if we teach a subject, let's teach it well !). See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names)

Comment: While you can access global variables without the global keyword, if you want to modify them you have to use the global keyword or a new local variable with same name as the global variable will be created.

Comment: @IMCoins PEP 8 actually suggests `__all__` *before* "the older" underscores method. And only *if* it's supposed to be non-public to begin with.

Comment: @JosephM Not if you *mutate* the object itself.

Comment: @deceze I agree, but then, if you want to suggest using it, we need to explain it, and it will take a much longer lesson imo, especially for someone that new to python.

Comment: @IMCoins Well then let's not get into such orthogonal issues at all here…

Comment: @deceze After some testing I stand corrected, global keyword is not needed for mutation.

Answer (score -2):

You haven't defined `wordList` before you try to use it in your loop or return it.

Try adding `wordList = []` below `i=0` to declare `wordList` as an empty list.

Also, you should use `wordList.append(i)` to add your word this list.

Comment: Note that this will lead to an `IndexError`, the way the list is used here…

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention that the developer will need to append to the list also.